# Converting MS-Word to PDF

Tags: asp.net, ms-word

I know this question has been made many times. I need to convert MS-Word documents, that are stored in a Windows Server 2003 web server, to PDF. That web server doesn't have any MS-Office components installed.

I think I have a couple of options:

1- Use Aspose.Word component, but its price is quite high for us.

2- Program my asp.net web application to send any MS-Word document to a virtual PDF printer. For instance, PDFCreator should be previously installed in Windows Server 2003.

I think option number 2 would be more practical.

My question is:
Would be possible in an asp.net application to send a Word document to a PDF printer? Could you point me out any tutorial on how to accomplish this?

Comment: In an asp.net application for .net framework 4.5/5 you can do all almost  stuff you can imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual PDF printers are your best choice. Try Bullzip PDF Printer (http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php) 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

public Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDocument { get; set; }
public void ConvertWord2Pdf(string Source, string Target)
{
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application appWord = new          
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Add(Source);
wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(Target, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
}
```

Add reference microsoft word 12.0 object library.
run->dcomcnfg in that change microsoft office word properties.
Authentication level-None.
Security Tab Add current user(if it is iis then add iis user) give full access permission.
Identity Tab select Interactive user.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual printers like PDF-XChange which provides 'Print to PDF' method might be another option..